# YouTube comments: why can't I see replies when I go to YouTube from an email notification?

Tags: youtube, comments

I often get email notifications that someone has replied to my post on YouTube. When I click on the link in the email to "see all comments" that comment is often not there.

What is that about?

How can I find that comment?

How can I reply to that comment?

Comment: How many comments are there? A lot or not very many?

Answer (score 2):

> **Note: As of October 18, 2021, the URL [youtube.com/comments](https://www.youtube.com/comments) leads to a 404, meaning the answer below no longer works.**

Try checking [youtube.com/comments](https://www.youtube.com/comments).

If YouTube thinks a comment may be of low quality, it will sometimes hold comments for manual review before publicly displaying them on a video. If you've been emailed about a comment and you can't find it on your video, it's more than likely being held for review, or was marked as spam.

[image: Review comments]

---

*<sup>Note: This answer was originally posted on the similar, possibly duplicate question [It won't let me see other peoples comments on my YouTube videos that I post. How do I fix this?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/103280/60818)</sup>*

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/comments leads to a 404 page

Comment: @LukeGriffiths Thanks for the update. Updated my answer to say the page no longer exists.

Answer (score 0):

It's a YouTube glitch I think; I often get it too. I waited it out and sometimes it will appear and sometimes will not. Just wait. YouTube still needs to fix it though.