# It won't let me see other peoples comments on my YouTube videos that I post. How do I fix this?

Tags: youtube

It won't let me see other peoples comments on my YouTube videos that I post. I get the notifications, but when I get on the video the comment isn't there, it says I have comments but nothing is there. How do I fix this? Cause people have been asking me if I want shout outs, but I can't reply or even see their comments.

Comment: do you see the comments in http://youtube.com/comments, perhaps in the "likely spam" tab?

Answer (score 1):

> **Note: As of October 18, 2021, the URL [youtube.com/comments](https://www.youtube.com/comments) leads to a 404, meaning the answer below no longer works.**

As [Leo Wattenberg suggested](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/103280/it-wont-let-me-see-other-peoples-comments-on-my-youtube-videos-that-i-post-how#comment90245_103280), try checking [youtube.com/comments](https://www.youtube.com/comments).

If YouTube thinks a comment may be of low quality, it will sometimes hold comments for manual review before publicly displaying them on a video. If you've been notified about a comment and you can't find it on your video, it's more than likely being held for review, or was marked as spam.

[image: Review comments]